dnsmasq in Podman
We have created a podman container in client server which doesn't have root permission,
I'm trying to resolve 4 DNS for Kerberos Authentication which does not have a common DNS.
My resolv.conf is:
servername 127.0.0.1

But inside my container its taking:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

My dnsmaq.conf:
user=dnsmasq
group=dnsmasq

listen-address=127.0.0.1
# Include all files in /etc/dnsmasq.d except RPM backup files
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.rpmnew,.rpmsave,.rpmorig

# Primary DNS Servers
server=/example1/dns1
server=/example2/dns2
server=/example3/dns3

# Secondary DNS Servers
server=/example1/dns1
server=/example2/dns2
server=/example3/dns3


Have this command which sets it manually but I want to run it through Ansible Automation Platform:
podman run --dns 127.0.0.1 -it localhost/example /bin/bash
Tried with 127.0.0.11 and 127.1.1.11 not able to resolve

I'm not sure exactly what your question is here, sorry.
